# How can I add drag and drop div with jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to make html page like kanban template. There are Todo, Doing and Done column lists in html page. And an user can move div to another column list under this lists.  But I couldn't manage to drag and drop div components with jquery. Is there problem with javascript code or anything else? I will very pleased if give an idea. Thank you in advance..

```js
$(function() {
  var kanbanCol = $('.panel-body');
  kanbanCol.css('max-height', (window.innerHeight - 150) + 'px');
  var kanbanColCount = parseInt(kanbanCol.length);
  $('.container-fluid').css('min-width', (kanbanColCount * 350) + 'px');

  draggableInit();

  $('.panel-heading').click(function() {
    var $panelBody = $(this).parent().children('.panel-body');
    $panelBody.slideToggle();
  });
});

function draggableInit() {
  var sourceId;
  $('[draggable=true]').bind('dragstart', function(event) {
    sourceId = $(this).parent().attr('id');
    event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.setData("text/plain", event.target.getAttribute('id'));
  });

  $('.panel-body').bind('dragover', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
  });

  $('.panel-body').bind('drop', function(event) {
    var children = $(this).children();
    var targetId = children.attr('id');

    if (sourceId != targetId) {
      var elementId = event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.getData("text/plain");

      $('#processing-modal').modal('toggle'); //before post

      // Post data 
      setTimeout(function() {
        var element = document.getElementById(elementId);
        children.prepend(element);
        $('#processing-modal').modal('toggle'); // after post
      }, 1000);
    }

    event.preventDefault();
  });
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div id="sortableKanbanBoards" class="row">
    <div class="panel panel-primary kanban-col">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        TODO
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="TODO" class="kanban-centered">
          <article class="kanban-entry grab" id="item1" draggable="true">
            <div class="kanban-entry-inner">
              <div class="kanban-label">
                <h2><a href="#">Art Ramadani 1</a></h2>
                <p>Tolerably earnestly middleton extremely distrusts she boy now not.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary kanban-col">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        DOING
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="DOING" class="kanban-centered">
          <article class="kanban-entry grab" id="item2" draggable="true">
            <div class="kanban-entry-inner">
              <div class="kanban-label">
                <h2><a href="#">Art Ramadani 2</a></h2>
                <p>Tolerably earnestly middleton extremely distrusts she boy now not.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel panel-primary kanban-col">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        DONE
        <i class="fa fa-2x fa-plus-circle pull-right"></i>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div id="DONE" class="kanban-centered">
          <article class="kanban-entry grab" id="item3" draggable="true">
            <div class="kanban-entry-inner">
              <div class="kanban-label">
                <h2><a href="#">Art Ramadani 3</a></h2>
                <p>Tolerably earnestly middleton extremely distrusts she boy now not.</p>
              </div>
            </div>
          </article>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="modal modal-static fade" id="processing-modal" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-body">
        <div class="text-center">
          <i class="fa fa-refresh fa-5x fa-spin"></i>
          <h4>Processing...</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are simply looking for something like this, for reference you can  [use](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists)

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>jQuery UI Sortable - Connect lists</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
  <style>
  #sortable1, #sortable2 {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    width: 142px;
    min-height: 20px;
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 5px 0 0 0;
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
  }
  #sortable1 li, #sortable2 li {
    margin: 0 5px 5px 5px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 1.2em;
    width: 120px;
  }
  </style>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  <script>
  $( function() {
    $( "#sortable1, #sortable2" ).sortable({
      connectWith: ".connectedSortable"
    }).disableSelection();
  } );
  </script>
</head>
<body>
 
<ul id="sortable1" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-default">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
<ul id="sortable2" class="connectedSortable">
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 1</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 2</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 3</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 4</li>
  <li class="ui-state-highlight">Item 5</li>
</ul>
 
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

a good example using jquery to achieve kanban - [pen link](https://codepen.io/riktar/pen/KqZpgL)

library used [jkanban](https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/riktar/jkanban/master/dist/jkanban.min.js)

```js
var KanbanTest = new jKanban({
        element : '#myKanban',
        gutter  : '10px',
        click : function(el){
            //alert(el.innerHTML);
           // alert(el.dataset.eid)
        },
        boards  :[
            {
                'id' : '_todo',
                'title'  : 'To Do (drag me)',
                'class' : 'info',
                'item'  : [
                    {
                       'id':'task-1',
                        'title':'Try drag me',
                    },
                    {
                       'id':'task-2',
                        'title':'Click me!!',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : '_working',
                'title'  : 'Working',
                'class' : 'warning',
                'item'  : [
                    {
                        'title':'Do Something!',
                    },
                    {
                        'title':'Run?',
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                'id' : '_done',
                'dragTo' : ['_working'],
                'title'  : 'Done (Drag only in Working)',
                'class' : 'success',
                'item'  : [
                    {
                        'title':'All right',
                    },
                    {
                        'title':'Ok!',
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    });

    var toDoButton = document.getElementById('addToDo');
    toDoButton.addEventListener('click',function(){
        KanbanTest.addElement(
            '_todo',
            {
                'title':'Test Add',
            }
        );
    });

    var addBoardDefault = document.getElementById('addDefault');
    addBoardDefault.addEventListener('click', function () {
        KanbanTest.addBoards(
            [{
                'id' : '_default',
                'title'  : 'Default (Can\'t drop in Done)',
                'dragTo':['_todo','_working'],
                'class' : 'error',
                'item'  : [
                    {
                        'title':'Default Item',
                    },
                    {
                        'title':'Default Item 2',
                    },
                    {
                        'title':'Default Item 3',
                    }
                ]
            }]
        )
    });

    var removeBoard = document.getElementById('removeBoard');
    removeBoard.addEventListener('click',function(){
        KanbanTest.removeBoard('_done');
    });
```

```css
body{font-family: "Lato"; margin:0; padding: 0;}
#myKanban{overflow-x: auto; padding:20px 0;}

.success{background: #00B961; color:#fff}
.info{background: #2A92BF; color:#fff}
.warning{background: #F4CE46; color:#fff}
.error{background: #FB7D44; color:#fff}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css"></script>
<link href="https://www.riccardotartaglia.it/jkanban/dist/jkanban.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://gitcdn.xyz/repo/riktar/jkanban/master/dist/jkanban.min.js"></script>
<div class="container-fluid">
   <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
         <h1>jKanban</h1>
         <p>jKanban allow you to create and manage Kanban Board in your project! Try It!</p>
            <a class="btn-xl btn btn-default" href="https://github.com/riktar/jkanban" target="_blank">Fork on GitHub</a>
         <hr>
         <div id="myKanban"></div>
         <button class="btn btn-success" id="addDefault">Add "Default" board</button>
         <button class="btn btn-success" id="addToDo">Add element in "To Do" Board</button>
         <button class="btn btn-danger" id="removeBoard">Remove "Done" Board</button>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```